# Powershell equivalent of Linux timeout

Tags: windows, powershell

As part of a Powershell script I need to perform a task that is typically quick, but can sometimes take a long amount of time. I want to execute the task, then wait *either* for it fo finish *or* for set time to pass, whichever happens first. When either condition happens, I need the Powershell script to return back to the command prompt.

Here is the closest I've come up with (using ping as an example)

```
$x = Start-Process -Filepath "ping" -ArgumentList 'google.com -n 100' -NoNewWindow -PassThru; 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; 
try { Stop-Process -Id $x.Id -ErrorAction stop } catch {};
```

This will kill the process after the timoeout is reached (if it is still running) and return back to the prompt. However, it won't return to the prompt if the command successfully completes before timeout. This results in the script always taking however long is specified in the timeout value.

The desired semantics are similar or identical to Linux's [timeout](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-timeout-command/) command.

Requirements:

- If the task completes within timeout window, control returns to the script (a prompt is displayed)
- If the timeout is reached and the task is stil running, the task is killed and control returns to the script (a prompt is displayed)
- Output from the task must be printed/displayed to stdout
- Works over an SSH connection

Comment: Jobs might give you what you want -- `Wait-Job` accepts a `-Timeout`, `Receive-Job` fetches results and `Stop-Job` can kill a command.

Comment: Note that there is a - green-lighted, but not yet implemented as of v7.0 - [GitHub feature suggestion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5185) about adding a `-Timeout` parameter directly to `Start-Process`; a related request for `Invoke-Command` is [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5434).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to use ping instead of notepad.  I'm combining wait-process and "$?" into one statement with "$( )", because powershell "if" looks at the output, not the exit status.

```
start ping 'google.com -n 100'
if (-not $(wait-process ping 10; $?)) { 
  stop-process -name ping }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the requirement can be met by using a Stopwatch, you'll have to test the SSH connection.

```
$timeOut = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 5
$stopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

do {
    try { 
          Test-Connection -ComputerName google.ca -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
          $timeOut = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 0  #Stop the stopWatch, we got a response
    }
    catch { #Write-Host "No response" }
}
While ($stopWatch.elaspsed -lt $timeOut)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as stated in my question, use of `ping` was just an example. It looks like your code runs a command in a loop, checking each iteration to see if some amount of time has passed. This kind of works for my example since you replaced a single ping command wiht multipleTest-Connection commands. However, any _long-running task_ won't ever get past the first iteration, nor will it be killed early if the timeout passes.